# Using a slide-out menu for each tab in <md-tabs>

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to built a slide out menu for my application using angular material.

I have certain tabs, each of which will have a slide-out menu with different content. I have implemented this in the following manner:

```
<md-tab ng-repeat="tab in categories"
                              ng-disabled="tab.disabled"
                              label="{{tab.title}}"
                                md-on-select="setArray(tab.title,0)">

                            <!--Include a dropdown of sub-categories here -->
                            <div layout="row">
                                <md-menu id="sub-cat-button">
                                    <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </md-button>
                                    <md-menu-content width=6>
                                        <md-menu-item ng-repeat="sub_cat in tab.sub_cat">
                                            <md-button ng-click="setArray(sub_cat,1)">{{sub_cat}}</md-button>
                                        </md-menu-item>
                                    </md-menu-content>
                                </md-menu>
                                <ol class="breadcrumb" id="breadcrumb">
                                    <li ng-repeat="link in bread"><a href="#">{{link}}</a></li>
                                </ol>

                                <md-sidenav md-component-id="right" class="md-sidenav-right">
                                    <md-button ng-click="openRightMenu()">
                                        <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>
                                    </md-button>
                                </md-sidenav>
                                <md-content>

                                    <md-button ng-click="openRightMenu()">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </md-button>
                                </md-content>
                            </div>

                            <div class="demo-tab tab{{$index%4}}" id="scrollable-tabs">
                                <div class="row" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-disabled="busy">
                                    <div ng-repeat="p in products">
                                        <h3><div class="well">{{p.id}}</div></h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-show="busy">Loading more products....</div>
                                <br/>
                            </div>
</md-tab>
```

The problem here is that, the menu slides out and can be seen only for tab 1. If I go to tab 5 and click on the filter button to open that menu, the menu is not seen slid out with tab 6 , but it has been already slid out for tab 1. you can view it slide out when you go to tab 1.

How do I make it visible for each tab, because the content of the slide out menu is dependent on the tab which is opened?

Comment: Do you have any working example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a working example of a sidenav that can slide-out on clicking a button. What I want is the same thing for a number of tabs, each tab-content having a button to slide-open the menu, with the menu content dependent on the tab selected